# Cloud run python imports are 10x slower than local

Tags: python, google-cloud-run

examples:

fastapi local import : 300ms - Cloud Run import  : 3000ms

pandas local import : 200ms - Cloud Run import  : 2000ms

has anyone managed to see similar performance on Cloud Run and locally?

Could you share you Docker/YaML in such case?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have in local? How fast is your CPU threads? How many memory? Compare something comparable!!

Comment: I have Mac M1 and running on top of conda, fine  - leaving the comparison aside, do you think it is possible to make  "from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status" run within ~500 from a cold start?

Comment: I'm not a python expert. I wrote that article and it shown that Python has a terrible cold start sometime. I don't know how fastAPI impact the start, but if the cold start is a concern, I recommend to use Go or to set the min instance parameter to 1 (you will pay more, but no cold start). https://medium.com/google-cloud/serverless-performance-comparison-does-the-language-matter-c72a7191c799

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere makes sense, thank for your answer and reference!

Answer (score 2):

One issue might be the process of importing modules into your program. Python will compile the modules into bytecode.

For small imports, the delay is minor, but if you are importing large libraries the delay is noticeable.

Look into **python -m compileall .** when building your container. This will eliminate the bytecode compile step that will occur every time your container starts.

Comment: Thanks John, sounds like this could be a handy optimization! 
It barely made a difference for me with the FastAPI package though.
For know i decided to tactically retreat from the cold start solution.
The docker up time is longer than one second anyway... but I still hope to crack this in the future maybe with the help of further improvements in the platform